# Following up on a missing cost of living increase

Tags: raise

I received part of my increase but was also told I would get a cost of living. It's been 2 months and no increase. I asked HR and was told cost of living would be given at the same time with the other employees. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe _**asking them when the other employees would be getting it**_ would be a nice start

Answer (score 3):

First, ask to HR/payroll why you haven't received your cost of living increase.

Comment: I asked and was told cost of living would be given at the same time with the other employees. Is that even legal?

Comment: "is it legal" is offtopic for this site. Did you ask "and when will that be?" when they answered "at the same time with the other employees". Seems like you have your answer.

Comment: Not sure how I should approach this without sounding like a pest? However I feel like I should have received at the same time as my increase.  Or is this inappropriate?

Answer (score 2):

First who told you that you would be getting a pay raise and a cost of living raise? That is the person I would go to for further clarification. Tell him or her that you thought that meant at the same time as the pay raise but HR is telling you differently. And then ask him if he could clear up the confusion. HR might not have been told you were getting something out of the normal schedule, HR may not have agreed to change but he told  you without knowing that or he simply didn't make it clear which raise would happen when. Then ask for the specific paycheck you could expect to see it in.  The person who gave you the initial information is really the person who needs to clear up the misunderstanding.